# How to set up libraries for fPortfolio and call pfolioTargetReturn

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm debugging another author's code.  I think the code is right, but my system is setup wrong.  It's calling a function from a package, and getting an error message:

```
> fPortfolio::pfolioTargetReturn( Data, weights = wgts )
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘series<-’ for signature ‘"numeric", "matrix"’
```

The error messages itself says it can't find the method for this function signature, which means that the function call signature is wrong, or that the method isn't loaded or is obscured.

The parameters (Data & wgts) seem to be properly formed:

```
> str(Data)
Time Series:          
 Name:               object
Data Matrix:        
 Dimension:          431 13
...
> str( wgts )
 Named num [1:13] 0.038 0.1467 0.038 0.3 0.0228 ...
```

and the same parameters sent to pfolioTargetRisk seem to work okay:

```
> fPortfolio::pfolioTargetRisk( Data, weights = wgts )
 TargetRisk 
0.002415664
```

and if I replace wgts with a simpler vector, I get the same error:

```
> pfolioTargetReturn(Data, weights = rep(x=1/13, times=13))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘series<-’ for signature ‘"numeric", "matrix"’
```

I installed the library in many different ways: originally from my predecessor's packrat; most lately as per the contributors' wiki at https://wiki.rmetrics.org/install_rmetrics.  So I think I have all dependencies set up.  I think the problem is on my search path: that there's another "series <-" function set up in another package, obscuring mine.  My search path is:

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"         "package:fPortfolio" "package:fAssets"    "package:fBasics"   
 [5] "package:xts"        "package:zoo"        "package:timeSeries" "package:timeDate"  
 [9] "package:knitr"      "tools:rstudio"      "package:stats"      "package:graphics"  
[13] "package:grDevices"  "package:utils"      "package:datasets"   "package:methods"   
[17] "Autoloads"          "package:base"
```

How can I resolve this error message?

---

Update:
I've stepped thru the functions in the fPortfolio library, and arrived at a line where I get the same result

```
> series( Return ) <- x %*% weights
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘series<-’ for signature ‘"numeric", "matrix"’
```

which clearly fits everything we've seen so far.  x has long since been cast `as.matrix(Data)`, and weights is my `rep(x=1/13, times=13)` vector.

```
> dim(x)
[1] 431  13
> length(weights)
[1] 13
> str( x %*% weights )
 num [1:431, 1] 0.002000 -0.000000 -0.001000 0.002000 0.002000 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:431] "2012-05-17" "2012-05-20" "2012-05-21" "2012-05-22" ...
  ..$ : NULL
```

but it would seem to me that a 431x13 matrix matrix-multiplied by a 13 length vector should come up with a 431x1 matrix or a 431-length vector, and it looks like R is taking it as a 431x1 matrix.  It looks to me like the `series(Return)` fails similarly

```
> series(Return)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘series’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
> str(Return)
 Named num [1:431] -0.00100 -0.00200 -0.00500 -0.00200 0.00800 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:431] "2012-05-17" "2012-05-20" "2012-05-21" "2012-05-22" ...
```

---

So tracing thru the library, I find that my call

```
pfolioTargetReturn( Data, weights = wgts )
```

gets sent to

```
> pfolioTargetReturn
function (x, weights = NULL) 
{
    x = as.matrix(x)
    ans = mean(pfolioReturn(x = x, weights = weights))
    names(ans) = "TargetReturn"
    ans
}
<environment: namespace:fPortfolio>
> pfolioReturn
function (x, weights = NULL, geometric = FALSE) 
{
    weights <- as.vector(weights)
    if (geometric) {
        X <- t(colCumprods(1 + x) - 1)
        X <- rbind(diff(t(X * weights)))
        Return <- x[, 1]
        series(Return[+1, ]) <- x[1, ] %*% weights
        series(Return[-1, ]) <- rowSums(X)
    }
    else {
        Return <- x[, 1]
        series(Return) <- x %*% weights
    }
    colnames(Return) <- "pfolioRet"
    Return
}
<environment: namespace:fPortfolio>
```

which starts by sending my `Data` to x, and then casting it to a matrix in `x = as.matrix(x)`, and then sending it to `pfolioReturn`, where (since I left the `geometric` out, it defaults to FALSE).  The my wgts get sent to `weights` which get cast to a vector in `weights <- as.vector(weights)`.  Then

```
Return <- x[, 1]
series(Return) <- x %*% weights
```

`Return` comes back as a 431 length vector.  `x %*% weights` becomes that 431x1 matrix (discussed above), which is what we need.  `series <-` calls for a timeSeries and a matrix.  I have a vector and a matrix.  So now I'm thinking that the problem is the vector `Return` not being timeSeries.  My `Data` started as a timeSeries, and the `fPortfolio` library changed it to a vector in `Return <- x[, 1]`.

If I haven't made some kind of installation error (which I still sorta' can't believe), then you've just helped me find a bug in the library.  I added a line `Return <- as.timeSeries(Return)` to the `pfolioReturn` function, and now I'm getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error. `timeSeries::'series<-'` is expecting a matrix and you are not giving it one. First find the problem function in the error message:

```
getAnywhere(`series<-`)
#----------
A single object matching ‘series<-’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:timeSeries
# snipped rest of output-----------
```

Then see what it expects as arguments:

```
showMethods(timeSeries::`series<-`,  includeDefs=TRUE)
#-------------------
Function: series<- (package timeSeries)
x="timeSeries", value="ANY"
function (x, value) 
{
    callGeneric(x, as(value, "matrix"))
}


x="timeSeries", value="matrix"
function (x, value) 
{
    if (identical(dim(x), dim(value))) {
        x@.Data <- value
        if (!is.null(cn <- colnames(value))) 
            colnames(x) <- cn
        return(x)
    }
 #snipped rest of definiton:
```

The first thing it did was check for dimensional congruence although the code never got there because the signature was not satisfied:

Comment: I added a line `Return <- as.timeSeries(Return)` to the `pfolioReturn` function, and now I'm getting an answer.  I'm not sure yet quite what to make of that.  I'm going to have to track down the library's source code.

Comment: I posted a tracker on r-forge with code changes https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6060&group_id=156&atid=633